# Vertically center three divs, one inside another

Tags: html, css

This is what I aim to do. I have two circles. The inner one is fixed, the outer one is dynamic and grows/shrinks. The two circles should be concentric. So I am creating two divisions, giving border-radius as 50% to create the circles. I have vertically centered them using table-cell method. However, I now need to center the outer div vertically in body. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/G28t8/

```
function updateCircle(){
            document.getElementById("outercircle").style.width = parseInt(document.getElementById("outercircle").style.width.split("px")[0]) + 5 + "px";
            document.getElementById("outercircle").style.height = parseInt(document.getElementById("outercircle").style.height.split("px")[0]) + 5 + "px";
            document.getElementById("outercircle").style.lineHeight = document.getElementById("outercircle").style.height;

        }
```

Comment: The description is already good, but please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: Yes, we want to know how far you got before you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify layout display of html & body, and takes advantage of tables layout specifities:

example fiddle used for some similar question (remove divs unwanted ;) ):
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/jGtAv/3/

```
html {
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Will it function like a normal webpage once I start adding more elements like p and a?

Comment: All content will center middle if body's height is taller than heights of all content. div, p , should stack like normal. Give it a try yourself, edit the fiddle , fork it